# fatal: Not a valid object name: 'master'

Tags: git

I have a private server running git 1.7
When I

```
git init
```

a folder it doesn't create a master branch.
Cause when i do:

```
git branch
```

it doesn't list anything.
When I  do:

```
git --bare init
```

it creates the files.
When I type

```
git branch master
```

it says:

```
fatal: Not a valid object name: 'master'.
```

Comment: The same result when trying to generate a new branch: `git branch newbranch`

Comment: To clarify: as you said, **master** doesn't exist so  `git branch master` is trying to  create it, same as `git branch newbranch`.

The only difference is that **master** is (probably) your *current* branch so, e.g. if you `git log`, it says
`fatal: your current branch 'master' does not have any commits yet`

Answer (score 431, accepted):

> When I `git init` a folder it doesn't create a master branch

This is true, and expected behaviour. Git will not create a `master` branch until you commit something.

> When I do `git --bare init` it creates the files.

A non-bare `git init` will also create the same files, in a hidden `.git` directory in the root of your project.

> When I type `git branch master` it says "fatal: Not a valid object name: 'master'"

That is again correct behaviour. Until you commit, there *is no master* branch.

You haven't asked a question, but I'll answer the question I assumed you mean to ask. Add one or more files to your directory, and `git add` them to prepare a commit. Then `git commit` to create your initial commit and `master` branch.

Comment: So, what if I never wanted a branch-pointer called "master" at all? What if I wanted it to be called "main"? There's no way to start off with a different name for the first branch-pointer? No "git init" parameters? Could I maybe go change the name listed in .git/HEAD? Are there some other files I would need to alter, also?

Comment: @Jemenake Then init your repository, make a commit, and rename the branch. If you really want to avoid a "master" branch ever being created, edit `.git/HEAD`, and change `refs/heads/master` to `refs/heads/main`, but there *no reason at all* to do this. Just rename your branch after the first commit.

Comment: you can use `git checkout -b <branchname>` to change HEAD - you don't need to edit the file.

Comment: The last part was golden, TFS GIT comes with totally uninitialized git repo. So after first clone using SourceTree, nothing works, couldn't figure it out for a long time until "Then git commit to create your initial commit and master branch". Is there really no way to have master-local/remote without initial commit/push?

Comment: Last explanation helps me to understand the branch can't exist if there are no commits.

Comment: here is a question regarding 'Until you commit, there is no master branch.' Then why does the 'git status' show 'On Branch Master' before all these?

Comment: @Tinu presumably because that's the branch that will be created if you commit anything without creating a new branch first. It definitely doesn't exist at that stage. It can't be checked out or even reset to at that point. I've often seen people accidentally create completely different branch names as the primary branch because they used their ticket number as the first branch on a repo that was newly created (i.e. the primary branch would be something like `feature/FOO-123`). Those repos would literally not have a master branch at all.

Comment: Your *current* branch may not be an *existing* branch, it's just a name.
The implementation details are: `cat .git/HEAD` --> **ref: refs/heads/master**, `cat .git/refs/heads/master` --> **.git/refs/heads/master: No such file or directory**

Answer (score 51):

<sup>copying Superfly Jon's comment into an answer:</sup>

To create a new branch without committing on `master`, you can use:

```
git checkout -b <branchname>
```

Comment: but when u  git branch --all or git branch , u cant see anyone

Comment: @nativelectronic That's right. Even for me when I do git branch -all or git branch it just don't do anything

Comment: @GSN `git branch` only shows branches with commits. Try `git status` to see the current branch name even if it has no commits.

Comment: Assuming that the original question was essentially "I can't branch from an empty repo?", this is the correct answer because it shows succinctly that it is possible. I also think there is additional value in this answer for situations where a new repo is being populated but policy prevents committing directly to main/master without code review. This avoids the scenario of having to add files to a local branch that will never be merged.

Answer (score 32):

Git creates a master branch once you've done your first commit. There's nothing to have a branch for if there's no code in the repository.

Comment: But you need a new branch in order to push into master.

Comment: here is a question regarding 'Git creates a master branch once you've done your first commit.' Then why does the 'git status' show 'On Branch Master' before all these?

Answer (score 23):

You need to commit at least one time on master before creating a new branch.

Answer (score 19):

First off, when you create a "bare repository", you're not going to be doing any work with it (it doesn't contain a working copy, so the `git branch` command is not useful).

Now, the reason you wouldn't have a `master` branch even after doing a `git init` is that there are no commits: when you create your first commit, you will then have a `master` branch.

Comment: Okay thats clear. But when I commit it says:  fatal: empty ident

Comment: I fixed that to. But when I want to pull/fetch this repo from a other computer. Should I do git init there to?

Comment: @RoyvanZanten You could use `git clone` to save having to do a `git init` on the receiver side.

Comment: I managed to get it all working. No errors. But when I try to push it says: Writing objects <bla>bla> Total <3/3>  To SERVER    59fa0tweirdcod04 master> master     But when I check the files on the server nothing is there.

Comment: @RoyvanZanten Are you looking at the server *repository* or the server *working copy*? You need to do a `git checkout` if you want the WC to reflect what's in the `.git` directory (which is where you pushed).

Comment: The files are on my local machine and I want them to be pushed to the server repo. I just saw it pushes the branch to the server. But there just no files. And when I do a checkout on the server it says iam not in a working tree.

Comment: Also... I did a git --bare init on the server repo.

Comment: @RoyvanZanten You **really** don't want a bare repo if you're trying to inspect files by checking them out. You're going to have to learn the difference between the working copy and the repository in order for your world to make sense. What's going on is that you pushed the files to the server - successfully - which puts them **in the repository on the server** (contents of the `.git` directory). To see what I mean, why don't you try a fresh `git clone` from the server? I bet your changes will be in there.

Comment: So should I do a git init in the server repo then? Cause when I just push to the remote it says there is no repo on the server. Like you told me I did a git clone to my local machine and it said i cloned a empty branch.

Comment: here is a question regarding 'Until you commit, there is no master branch.' Then why does the 'git status' show 'On Branch Master' before all these?

Comment: @Tick20 when you make your first commit, it becomes `master`. Before there's a commit, there is no branch called `master`. In implementation terms, `.git/HEAD` may contain `ref: refs/heads/master`, but `.git/refs/heads/master` does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

This is because you have not committed anything yet.
First, you have to `use git add .` or `git add <file-name>` ,
then you have to use `git commit -m "committed successfully"`
now you can create a new branch.

Comment: Doesn't work. I want to create a new repository, then create a new branch `feature-branch`, write code in this branch, commit, then merge this `feature-branch` into `master`. I do this: `mkdir testrepo` then `cd testrepo` then `git init` then `git add .` then `git commit -m "committed successfully"` then `git branch feature-branch` and I **still** get the same error: `fatal: not a valid object name: 'master'`.

Answer (score 0):

please try to create any file in master branch and commit.Then create other branch . It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Not a traditional answer but I have a solution for my case too.
For this exact same issue, I noticed this issue occured when I created another repository in an already existing repository.

So if you cloned a repo and then `git init` again, it'll cause this issue. Then you have to delete the whole folder and clone it again. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

just do `git checkout -b branchname`. It should create the branch.

Answer (score 0):

Use an online git service to create a repository with a file and the desired branch already present.

Trying locally you encounter problems.

```
git init --bare new.git
cd new.git
git checkout -b next 
fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree
```

Searching online gets lots of good and bad advice, but no definitive solution.

What I did:

Create an initial public repository on a favored git service.  I favor GitHub
Set your default initial branch to whatever you like: I like "next".
Be sure to include the creation of a README.md and a License File of your choice.

Your repository is almost empty, and you can create a local bare clone that will already have a branch:

```
git clone --bare <gitURL> myrepo.git

Cloning into bare repository 'cpp.git'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 5, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Total 5 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (5/5), 12.68 KiB | 1.06 MiB/s, done.

cd myrepo.git
git worktree add /work/suites/cpp/next next
Preparing worktree (checking out 'next')
HEAD is now at 4255e58 Initial commit
```

Alternatively, you could create a git locally but not a bare one, add your first file and then convert it to a bare repository.  You can find instructions to do that using a search engine.