# Local machine pushes branch but no files to Remote repo

Tags: git

When I push from my local machine to my remote repo with git it gives no errors.
It counts the objects, compresses them and says: 'master > master'.
But when I check my remote repo i only see the new branch, there no new files added to the directory.
When I try to switch to that branch on the remote server with 'git checkout master' it says iam not in a working tree.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks

PS: The remote repo is initalized with:  'git init'

Comment: Possibly duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283262/what-is-a-git-work-tree-why-have-i-never-needed-to-set-this-as-an-env-var-why)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remote repository is most likely a bare repo and created with git init --bare.

To see the files, create a separate non bare clone of the bare repository.

To verify the changes are in, use git log

Comment: I am pretty sure the server remote repo is not bare. Is there nothing else that can explain this?

Comment: If it's not bare, you should not push into it. Git usually forbids pushing into the checked out branch. The effects on the index are very unintuitive to git beginners in such a case.

Comment: So if i push my code to my remote repo the intention of git is that i do not push the files but the changes made into branch? But what if i want to pull the code where do i get the files from then if i dont have the files?

Comment: Also check out what Borealid posted on a previous git problem i had. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162271/fatal-not-a-valid-object-name-master#comment11527740_9162348