# How do I branch out from an empty master branch

Tags: git, branch

I have cloned an empty repository. I have an empty master branch. I need to branch out to a dev branch and start my development code there. Later I might not even need the master branch but some stable branch to keep my stable code.

When I use git branch dev it says fatal: not a valid object 'master'.

But when I commit a file inside the master it allows me to branch out.

Comment: hm?  Why create a dev branch to keep stable code in when you already have the master?  If you anticipate introducing unstable code, wouldn't that be the time to branch, and if it ends up working, merge back into the master?

Comment: the 'stable' branch will be for stable code and 'dev' for development. that stable can be 'master' also

Comment: To have a branch, git requires you to have at least one commit, then it will create the master branch from its reference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [fatal: Not a valid object name: 'master'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162271/fatal-not-a-valid-object-name-master)

Comment: Ok so its the way Git works. So I can add the initial files do a commit in master and branch out to dev, and maybe later delete master if not required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have a branch, git requires you to have at least one commit, then it will create the master branch from its reference.

If you are going to delete `master` afterwards, and you already have multiple branches, you must:

```
git checkout your_chosen_branch
git branch -D master
```

Doing this will update the `HEAD` reference to point to `your_chosen_branch`. Otherwise you'll have to do this manually:

```
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/your_chosen_branch
```

Answer (score 0):

If its only a matter of one commit, just make a dummy file (may be `readme`  or even better - `.gitignore` file) and make the first commit, then branch out.

(It seems you want to follow some principles, and be strict about it, like creating a dev branch and all.. My advice is don't overdo it, and be flexible about things :). )

Answer (score 0):

If you really *really* don't want a "master" branch, you can go to the .git directory and edit the HEAD file, replacing "master" with whatever name you choose.

In the case of a cloned empty repository, you'd probably want to do that on the bare repo before cloning. (In case you are wondering: Yes, I've had to do this.)