# Issues with creating standalone app using Brackets-Shell

Tags: adobe-brackets, brackets-shell

I have a web app that I'm trying to package up into a standalone app using Brackets-Shell. I followed the instructions here to setup Brackets and Brackets-Shell on my Mac OSX system:

https://github.com/adobe/brackets-shell/wiki/Building-brackets-shell

And seemed to be able to generate the Brackets.app file by running 'grunt full-build -v' from within the Brackets-Shell folder.

I then followed the instructions here to modify the Gruntfile.js file in the Brackets-Shell folder to use the source from my web app:

http://clintberry.com/2013/html5-desktop-apps-with-brackets-shell/

But, now when I run the 'grunt full-build -v' command I get the following error message:

```
>Build branch master
> 
> Running "build-num" task
> /Users/dave/Desktop/Bracket_Shell/dev-tools/my-app
> git log --format=%h
> fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'
> fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'
>Warning: Task "build-num" failed. Use --force to continue.
```

I'm not sure how to get past this error (I'm definitely a newbie at using grunt). Any suggestions or help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Is `/Users/dave/Desktop/Bracket_Shell/dev-tools/my-app` the correct location of your web app?
2. Are you using Git for source control? Mind this part of the instructions:

   > **Use Git for your HTML app** – To use the build scripts provided by brackets, you need to be using Git with your source code. If you aren’t using git for your project, cd into your project folder and type `git init`

   Note that the instructions aren't 100% complete – if you aren't using git already, you'll need to create at least one commit after doing `git init` (otherwise the `git log` call in the build script will still fail).  You can just pick any small file in your "my-app" folder and do `git add <file>` and then `git commit -m "Create repo"`.

Comment: Yes, the "my-app" folder location contains my web app files (i.e., it has the index.html file as well as other associated files). Also, I'm not familiar with Git, so if I need to do anything special with it then I probably didn't do it. I did cd into my-apps folder and type in "git init" before I ran the grunt full-build command.

Comment: If you go to the "my-app" folder and run `git log` manually, do you see the same error about "HEAD" as above? What about `git status`? And what do you see if you type `ls .git`?

Comment: `git log` returns "fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'", and `git status` returns "On branch master","Initial commit", then a list of my-app's files and folders plus a short list of untracked files (which are not necessary for the web app). finally, `ls .git` returns this: "HEAD config description hooks index info objects refs".

Comment: Aha - I think this means you've done the initial `git init` but nothing else. The master branch doesn't exist until you make at least one commit ([see this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9162347/1172352)). If you're not using Git for your actual source control, just pick any small file in my-app and do `git add <file>` then `git commit -m "Create repo"`. Will update my answer above and post a comment on the original article you linked.

Comment: Thanks, ytpete! After I did the git commit command I was able to get Grunt to make it past that error message. Cool! However, I'm now stuck at a different point during the Grunt process with a different error message.