# New Git repository has no "master" branch

Tags: git

I just created a new git repository and only did one commit.  Now I do not see a master branch.  These are roughly the commands I ran.

- git init
- git checkout -b dev
- (I made some changes to the monitored directory)
- git add --all
- git commit -m "a message"

Now when I do a "git branch -a" I do not see a master and if I do "git checkout -b master" I get an error.  After reading "[fatal: Not a valid object name: 'master'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162271/fatal-not-a-valid-object-name-master)" I see that this is expected behavior.  My understanding is that it is typical (and desirable) for repositories to have a master branch.

So I have 2 questions.  What are the steps that I should have followed to keep the master branch?  What should I do now to get the master branch back?

Thank you in advance for any help
Joe

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "master" branch has no special status. You can create it or delete it whenever you want just like you would with any other branch.

You'd have gotten a master if you'd committed before creating a branch yourself (so if you'd done your step 2 after the first commit).

Now if you just:

```
git checkout -b master
```

You'll have a master branch.

Comment: Thank you, I did not realize that master was the same as any other branch.  Is it best practice to keep a master branch?  Or could you point me to an article that discusses this?  Thanks!

Comment: It's unusual not to have a master branch. But that's about it. If your workflow doesn't need it, well, you don't need it.