# How do you create the 'master' branch on git if you forgot to create it before branching?

Tags: git, branch

Someone recently created a repo locally, branched off, and only pushed the branch to remote. Is it possible for another person to create the 'master' branch without any commits, and push it to the remote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You cannot have a branch with no commits, and no `master` branch *ever* has no commits. `master` does not exist in a Git repository until your first commit.

When you make a new Git repository, `.git/refs/HEAD` will contain the following:

```
ref: refs/heads/master
```

*However*, `refs/heads/master` does not yet exist, and won't until you commit. There *is* no `master` branch until your first commit, and there is nothing to push.

You can use `git log` to find your earliest commit, and create `master` pointing to that commit, which is exactly what would happen with a new repository.

For more information: [fatal: Not a valid object name: 'master'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162271/fatal-not-a-valid-object-name-master/9162347#9162347)

Comment: I would only that by definition, a branch is a pointer to a commit. So it follows that you cannot have a branch without a commit. http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-What-a-Branch-Is