# Cannot implement gitflow

Tags: git, version-control, branch, git-flow

I want to implement [gitflow workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow). So I need to create the develop branch first and only then if new release is detected to merge it into the master branch with a tagname of release. But it gives me an error. Any ideas?

NOTE: I don't have any master branch just yet, because I don't have any release

```
git init
git branch develop
```

**error**:

```
fatal: Not a valid object name: 'master'.
```

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162271/fatal-not-a-valid-object-name-master/9162347) post. While not exactly the same problem as yours, it states that the master branch is not created until you commit something. I briefly looked at the Gitflow Workflow docs you provided and it looks like the tool utilizes the master branch. It seems that you're trying to do this in a newly created repo, committing something might solve your problem.